# .htacces rewrite all to index / ignore images and css files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I use the following .htaccess file to send all my requests to the index file.
But now I would like to ignore everything that comes from the `/static` folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

So here's the thing:

```
- index.php
- static/
----img
--------bg.jpg
----css
--------main.css
```

Currently it is so that on subpages of the style and the images can no longer be loaded. And I would like to renounce the use of complete paths.

Comment: Sorry, was to late for me, yesterday

Comment: `!-f` should already prevent files that do exist from being rewritten to index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/static/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Using `THE_REQUEST` is preferred for negative conditions as `THE_REQUEST` variable is not overwritten with other rules.

Comment: I tried it, but the url looks now like this: `http://localhost/gemeinde/event/register/static/img/logo.png`and it should look like this: `http://localhost/gemeinde/static/img/logo.png` this part is the base link: `http://localhost/gemeinde`

Comment: You asked for a rule to ignore static files and this is what this rule is doing. Now it looks like you a different problem. How are you using image link in your HTML page?

Comment: `<im src='static/img/logo.png'>` I can not set /static/ because the page could be in a subfolder.

Comment: To fix this issue, you need to add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/gemeinde/" />`

Comment: @anubhava, Hello sir, so `THE_REQUEST` url means like `http:test.singh.com/test/test/static/test`? And it checks that no static keyword found in that request? Will be grateful if you could guide here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to add an exception, right?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working, that is a image tag I use `<img src="static/img/logo.png" alt="logo" height="60px">`. When I visit a link like example.com/event/edit the logo is missing.

Comment: I assume this is a question of relative path versus absolute path. You provided little information about the actual setup you have. Have a try with that condition instead: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/static/`...